# E0020 identifier "pop" is undefined

Tags: c++, queue

I realy don't know what i need to do to fix this. Iam using Visual. Precompilied headers off, sdl check off. Task is "Find the vertices of the graph that are in the back distance from the vertex"

Main file:

```
#include "Header.h"
int main()
{
    int start, length, number;
    char file1[] = "data.txt";
    char file2[] = "result.txt";
    queue **graph = NULL;
    input(&number, &start, &length, &graph, file1);
    queue *buffer = new queue({ NULL, NULL });
    search(&number, &start, &length, &graph, &buffer);
    output(&buffer, file2, start, length);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Header.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "vertex.h"

//ввод
void input(int *number, int *start, int *lenght, queue ***graph, char file[])
{
    int v1, v2;
    char c;
    FILE*  in = fopen(file, "r");
    if (in)
    {
        fscanf(in, "%d %d %d\n", number, start, lenght); //считывается количество вершин, начальная вершина, длина пути и определяется ориентированный ли граф
        *graph = new queue*[*number];   //область, куда будет записываться список смежности 
        for (int i = 0; i < *number; i++)
            (*graph)[i] = new queue({ NULL, NULL });

        for (int i = 0; i < *number; i++)       //ввод списка смежности
        {
            fscanf(in, "%d", &v2);  //считывание строки
            fscanf(in, "%c", &c);   //проверка есть ли элементы

            while (c != '\n')
            {
                if (fscanf(in, "%d", &v1)) //считывание граничащих вершин
                {
                    push((*graph)[v2], v1);
                    push((*graph)[v1], v2);
                }
                fscanf(in, "%c", &c);   //проверка есть ли еще элементы
            }
        }
        fclose(in);
    }
}

//вывод
void output(queue **buffer, char text[], int start, int length)
{
    FILE *out = fopen(text, "w");
    if (!(*buffer)->begin)
    {
        fprintf(out, "От вершины %d нет вершин на пути длинной %d", start, length);
        return;
    }
    while ((*buffer)->begin)            //выводятся все элементы очереди
    {
        int a;
        pop(*buffer, a);
        fprintf(out, "%d ", a);
    }
    fclose(out);
}

void step(int* numE, int* numO, bool** odd, queue ***graph, queue** qu)
{
    while (*numE > 0)       //Элементы будут добавляться пока не пройдут все
    {               //элементы добавленные на прошлом шагу
        int n;
        pop(*qu, n);            //Элемент из очереди
        vertex* d = (*graph)[n]->begin; //Обход граничащих с n элементов
        while (d != NULL)       //Пока не пройдут все граничущие элементы
        {
            if (!(*odd)[d->value])
            {
                push(*qu, d->value);        //В очередь граничащего элемен-та
                (*odd)[d->value] = true;    //ставим флажок добавленный элемент     
                (*numO)++;
            }
            d = d->next;        //Переход к следующему граничащему элементу
        }
        (*numE)--;
    }

}

//поиск вершин у связного графа
void search(int *number, int *start, int *length, queue ***graph, queue **comp)
{
    bool* even = new bool[*number];     //Массив для хранения вершин на четном ходу
    bool* odd = new bool[*number];  //Массив для хранения вершин на нечетном ходу 
    bool flag = false;          //Флажок на проверку изолированную вершину
    int numO = 1, numE = 0;     //Количество добавленных элементов во время прошлого хода
    queue* qu = new queue({ NULL, NULL });// записываются новые элементы
    for (int i = 0; i < *number; i++)   //Обнуление массивов
    {
        odd[i] = 0;
        even[i] = 0;
    }
    push(qu, *start);           //Добавление стартового элемента
    odd[*start] = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < *length; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2)
        {
            if (!numE)  break;
            step(&numE, &numO, &odd, graph, &qu);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!numO)
                break;
            step(&numO, &numE, &even, graph, &qu);
            if (!flag && numE)      //если было добавление, то убираем флажок 
                flag = true;
        }

    }
    if (*length % 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < *number; i++)
            if (even[i])
                push(*comp, i);
    }
    else
        if (flag || *length == 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < *number; i++)
                if (odd[i])
                    push(*comp, i);

}
```

vertex.h:

```
struct vertex
{
    int value; vertex *next;
};

struct queue
{
    vertex *begin; vertex *end;
};

void input(int *number, int *start, int *lenght, queue ***graph, char file[]);
void output(queue **buffer, char text[], int start, int length);
void step(int* numE, int* numO, bool** odd, queue ***graph, queue** qu);
void search(int *number, int *start, int *length, queue ***graph, queue **comp);
```

E0020 identifier "pop" is undefined
E0020 identifier "push" is undefined
C3861 'push': identifier not found
C3861 'pop': identifier not found

Comment: where is your declaration of `push` and `pop`?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to implement `queue` and its related functions.

Comment: That's a horrible amount of manual memory management. Why would you do that?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, i just forgot to implement pop and push functions.
vertex.h:

```
struct vertex
{
    int value; vertex *next;
};

struct queue
{
    vertex *begin; vertex *end;
};

void push(queue* &p, int elem)
{

    vertex *temp = new vertex({ elem, NULL });
    if (!p->begin)
    {
        p->begin = temp;
        p->end = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        p->end->next = temp;
        p->end = p->end->next;

    }

}

void pop(queue* &p, int &elem)
{
    if (!p->begin) return;
    vertex *temp = p->begin;
    elem = p->begin->value;
    p->begin = p->begin->next;
    if (!p->begin)
        p->end = NULL;
    delete temp;
}

void input(int *number, int *start, int *lenght, queue ***graph, char file[]);
void output(queue **buffer, char text[], int start, int length);
void step(int* numE, int* numO, bool** odd, queue ***graph, queue** qu);
void search(int *number, int *start, int *length, queue ***graph, queue **comp);
```